How to only allow keys from a union as an indexer, but not require all of them
I am trying to create a type that only allows keys from a union and tried the key in statement, yet the implemented types now require all keys to be present.
How can I define the type so that not all values have to be present?
const widgetConditions = ['boxed', 'loose', 'preorder'] as const
export type WidgetCondition = (typeof widgetConditions)[number]

export type WidgetSummaryData = {
  [key: string]: {
    [key in WidgetCondition]: number
  }
}

const widgetSummary: WidgetSummaryData = {
  '1': {
    boxed: 1,
    loose: 2
    // error here as preorder is not supplied
  },
  '2': {
    boxed: 4,
    loose: 5,
    preorder: 6
  }
} satisfies WidgetSummaryData


[key in WidgetCondition]?: number makes them optional

Thanks, @apokryfos - add the answer so I can credit ya

I'm surprised I can't easily find a duplicate for this, so @apokryfos really should write an answer (and link to the docs for mapping modifiers)

@jcalz, yeah I really did look and plenty examples of using all the keys, but not optional ones. Hopefully helps others

When you are using mapped types, you can add the modifiers of readonly to make them readonly in the new type, and/or ? to make them optional in the new type.
In your case you'd do:
export type WidgetSummaryData = {
  [key: string]: {
    [key in WidgetCondition]?: number
  }
}

This makes them all optional.
All the possible ways you can modify mapped types are also found in the manual
